# getting value from binding source in vb.net 2013

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I want to get a specific value from a specific row in a table loaded by a binding source.
now I have this :

```
Me.Diplomes_BS.Filter = "PERSONNEID = " & Me.personneid_TB.Text
```

but I want to replace the 'Text box' with the specific value .
how can I do that ??

Comment: Me.Diplomes_BS.Filter = "PERSONNEID = YOUR VALUE HERE"   -  Am I missing something in your question???

Comment: I want the value of the column x of the current row in binding source ...

Comment: Not at all how I read that. You will want to use the windows.currencymanager to get the current item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
Dim currentRow = DirectCast(sitPerso_BS.Current, DataRowView)

    Dim idpersonne As Integer = DirectCast(currentRow.Row, appli.agentDB_DataSet.situation_personnelleRow).PERSONNEID
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current item, when using ANY type of windows binding, you can use the currency manager to get the current item. Sample Code:

```
dim CM as CurrencyManager = CType(BindingContext(Diplomes_BS), CurrencyManager)
```

That will return you a currency manager. From that, you can use something like this to get the current item:

```
If (CM.Count > 0) Then
    dim d as Diplomes = CType(CM.Current, Diplomes)
    '... Your code to get the value you want
    'IE
    dim i as int32 = d.personneid
End If
```

Comment: I don't understand the type "Diplomes", is it the data member of Diplomes_BS? if so, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you don't know then I'm afraid I cant help you. I assumed by looking at the code that you had a binding source filled with objects of type "Diplomes" since it was called "Diplomes_BS". It should be what ever type of object you have in there.